# Why does the iframe fail to load because of the special characters in the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This URL: https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?citybyzipcode  won't show in an frame because of the question mark. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Nothing to do with `?`, the website doesn't allow other websites to load via iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Mr. Alien, the issue lies in the web page itself, not the question mark (which indicates a POST parameter and is not really part of the URL).

USPS doesn't allow people to iFrame that specific web page. They clearly are looking to protect their IP by preventing this functionality, so there isn't a workaround that would be considered legal.

Comment: Ok thanks. Other child pages within the usps.com parent site load fine. I also could not find xframe option when debugging. Oh well. Good to know.

Comment: No problem! 
Other pages load that aren't protected because they don't host any proprietary features like address validation (which is something that companies pay a lot of money for).

As a reminder, please accept the best answer when you've solved the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Your comment is the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The following message is displayed in the console:

`Refused to display 'https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?citybyzipcode' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

This means that USPS does not allow people to create `iframe` tags using their website as the `src`.